# Using php to run a JavaScript that edits the css after a from is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

After the user submits a form the .php file is supposed to display only certain parts of the forum depending on if cc_owner has a value of personal or something else.  I have the contents to be displayed in two separate div elements one called CreditContent_ID and the other called BillContent_ID the inline css sets both div display elements to 'none'. I am trying to use php to check whether the value of cc_owner is personal or something else. If it's personal I want it to change the CreditContent_ID display to block.

I think the problem is with this line:

```
echo 'document.getElementById("CreditContent_ID").style.display="block"';
```

Here is my code:

```
<style>
    .CreditContent{
        display:none;

    }
    .BillContent{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <?php 
        if($_POST['cc_owner']=='personal'){
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'document.getElementById("CreditContent_ID").style.display="block"'; 
            echo '</script>';
        }else{
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'document.getElementById("BillContent_ID").style.display="block"';
            echo '</script>';

        }
    ?>
    <div class=CreditContent id="CreditContent_ID">
        //I have other code here.
    </div>
    <div class=BillContent id="BillContent_ID">
        //more code here
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the issue? is there any error?

Comment: instead of updating CSS using javascript why can't you update CSS using PHP?

Comment: ^^ Afterall you are doing a submit round trip to the PHP code on the server

Comment: Why not just put `<div class=CreditContent id="CreditContent_ID">` inside `if` and `<div class=BillContent id="BillContent_ID">` inside `else`? (would be nice to save this in cookie or something wo it will work after page reload)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.hideContent {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="CreditContent <?php echo $_POST['cc_owner'] != 'personal'? 'hideContent': ''; ?>" 
        id="CreditContent_ID">
        //I have other code here.
    </div>

    <div class="BillContent <?php echo $_POST['cc_owner'] == 'personal'? 'hideContent': ''; ?>" 
        id="BillContent_ID">
        //more code here
    </div>
</body>
```

Add css class `hideContent` to div based on `cc_owner` value.

Comment: I tried it, and it wasn't working for me. But I was able to make a few minor changes to get it working.  Thanks for your help! This is what I changed.  <div class="<?php if($_POST['cc_owner'] == 'personal'){echo 'hideContent';} ?>"  id="BillContent_ID">

Comment: @Kman don't forget to mark it as solution. However I would change the php-injection this way: `<?= $_POST['cc_owner'] === 'personal' ? 'hideContent' : '' ?>`